# Certain UIImageViews in puzzle game won't move to new CGPoint center

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, cgpoint

I have 8 UIImageViews in a frame of 9 equal spaces. All of the views except two (the top row) move to the `emptySpot` when touched. Can't figure out why.

(As a side note, I can't figure out why the first few lines of code in my blockquote don't format/show as code like the rest!?)

```
import UIKit  
import Foundation  
var tiledViewsStack = [UIImageView]()
var emptySpot = CGPoint()

class PhotoViewController: UIViewController,
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

//Choose an image from Photo Library and display on screen in displayImageView

@IBOutlet weak var displayImageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func choosePicFromLibrary(sender: AnyObject) {
    let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover

    if (imagePicker.popoverPresentationController != nil) {
        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = sender as! UIButton
        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = (sender as! UIButton).bounds
    }
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover

    if (imagePicker.popoverPresentationController != nil) {
        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = sender as! UIButton
        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = (sender as! UIButton).bounds
    }
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    displayImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage!
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}



//Cut photo into 9 tiles
    //Cut selected image into 9 pieces and add each cropped image to tileImageStack array

var tileImageStack = [AnyObject]()

var allCenters = [NSValue]()

@IBAction func randomize(sender: AnyObject) {

let selectedImageWidth = displayImageView.image!.size.width
let selectedImageHeight = displayImageView.image!.size.height

let tileSize = CGSizeMake(selectedImageWidth/3, selectedImageHeight/3)

    for (var colI = 0; colI < 3; colI++)
    {
        for (var rowI = 0; rowI < 3; rowI += 1)
        {
            let tileRect = CGRectMake(CGFloat(rowI) * tileSize.width, tileSize.height * CGFloat(colI), tileSize.width, tileSize.height)

            if let selectedImage = displayImageView.image
            {
                let tileImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(selectedImage.CGImage, tileRect)
                let aUItile = UIImage(CGImage: tileImage!)
                tileImageStack.append(aUItile)
            }
        }
    }

    //Display tiles in order on screen, then mix them up randomly

    let frameWidth = self.view.frame.width
    let frameHeight = self.view.frame.height

    var xCen = (frameWidth/3)/2
    var yCen = (frameHeight/3)/2

    var pieceNumber = 0

    for (var v = 0; v < 3; v += 1)
    {
        for (var h = 0; h < 3; h += 1)
        {
            let tiledView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frameWidth/3, (frameHeight)/3))
            var curCenter = CGPointMake(xCen, yCen)
            allCenters.append(NSValue(CGPoint: curCenter))
            //tiledView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            tiledView.center = curCenter
            tiledView.image = tileImageStack[pieceNumber] as? UIImage
            tiledView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            tiledViewsStack.append(tiledView)
            self.view.addSubview(tiledView)
            xCen += (frameWidth/3)
            pieceNumber += 1
        }
        xCen = (frameWidth/3)/2
        yCen += (frameHeight/3)
    }

    tiledViewsStack[0].removeFromSuperview()
    tiledViewsStack.removeAtIndex(0)
    //Now there are 8 imageViews in the tiledViewsStack array, and 9 centers stored in allCenters array.        

    var centersCopy = allCenters
    var randLocInt = Int()
    var randLoc = CGPoint()

    for any in tiledViewsStack
    {
        randLocInt = Int(arc4random() % UInt32(centersCopy.count)) // 0, --- 8
        randLoc = centersCopy[randLocInt].CGPointValue()
        any.center = randLoc
        centersCopy.removeAtIndex(randLocInt)
    }       
    emptySpot = centersCopy[0].CGPointValue()
}

var tapCen = CGPoint();

var left = CGPoint();
var right = CGPoint();
var top = CGPoint();
var bottom = CGPoint();

var leftIsEmpty = false
var rightIsEmpty = false
var topIsEmpty = false
var bottomIsEmpty = false


override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    let frameWidth = self.view.frame.width
    let frameHeight = self.view.frame.height

    let allTouches = event?.allTouches()
    let myTouch = allTouches?.first

    if myTouch!.view != self.view
    {
        tapCen = myTouch!.view!.center

        left = CGPointMake(tapCen.x - (frameWidth/3), tapCen.y)
        right = CGPointMake(tapCen.x + (frameWidth/3), tapCen.y)
        top = CGPointMake(tapCen.x, tapCen.y - (frameHeight/3))
        bottom = CGPointMake(tapCen.x, tapCen.y + (frameHeight/3))

        if (emptySpot == left) {leftIsEmpty = true}
        if (emptySpot == right) {rightIsEmpty = true}
        if (emptySpot == top) {topIsEmpty = true}
        if (emptySpot == bottom) {bottomIsEmpty = true}

        if (leftIsEmpty || rightIsEmpty || topIsEmpty || bottomIsEmpty)
        {
            //UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: myTouch!.view!.center = emptySpot, completion: true)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone, animations: { () -> Void in

                myTouch!.view!.center = emptySpot

                }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                })

            emptySpot = tapCen
            leftIsEmpty = false; rightIsEmpty = false; topIsEmpty = false; bottomIsEmpty = false;
        }
    }   
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
} }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use auto-layout then moving a view's center or frame often doesn't work as expected because the constraints override the view's position.

(It works until something causes the layout of the views to be updated. At that point the constraints override the changes you've made.)

With auto-layout you need to add outlets to your constraint(s) and then change the constant values on those constraints in order to move your views.

As for your code, indenting by > 4 spaces is what marks a block of text as code. Your first few lines were not indented enough. (I fixed it.)

BTW. There's no reason to use block quotes on your code. Select the code, click the curly braces code button on the editor, and it indents the code the required 4 spaces.

(I was too lazy to remove all the unneeded "> " block quote prefixes on your code lines. You should probably do that.)

Comment: Thanks for the formatting tips! 
I don't use auto layout to create any of the 9 puzzle tile UIImageViews— I do it programmatically in the second nested for loop. Would the Navigation controller bar at the top have something to do with it? 
Also, just curious: were/are you able to run and test this in a simulator?

Comment: Does the storyboard/XIB that holds your view controller have it's "Use AutoLayout" checkbox checked? It **is** checked by default, so the answer is very likely yes unless you remembered to turn it off.

Comment: Yes it was checked. I unchecked it for all the scenes/view controllers, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Use Auto Layout is a setting for an entire storyboard, not a scene by scene setting. It's under the "File Inspector" for the storyboard.

Comment: Right— I got the right setting, I just noticed the box remained unchecked when I clicked on various scenes in the document outline or view controllers in the storyboard.